The user should see a print result of their current field map
My problem is when I execute the program and insert the instructions I don't see that print the new value in array 2d.
print() {
        // I can prin the array, thanks design6726512087 he is in the forum of codecademy
        console.clear();
        this._fields.forEach(rows => {
            console.log(rows.join(''));
        });
    }
playGame() {
        while (!this.gameOver) {      
            this.print();      
            const promptInputUser = prompt("Instructions to move is: {u as up}, {d as down}, {l as left} & {r as right}.\nWich is your path? ");
            // Call the function to move into array 
            this.instructionsToMove(promptInputUser);
        }
        console.log("Game Over");
    }

When I call the function in playGame() to print the instruction in array but throw a problem: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach').
Also, I hope you can understand my English is not the better but I trying to write.
This is another part to move but I think that I have a problem here too.
        const input = promptInputUser.toLowerCase();
        if (input.toLowerCase === 'u') { // Move to up
            if (this.x > 0) { // Verify that is not move more to top edge
                this._fields[this.x][this.y] = this._pathCharacter; // Mark the path in the position
                this.x -= 1;
            } else {
                this.gameOver = true;  // In case the player find a hole
                console.log("You cannot move more above to edge.");
            }
        } else if (input.toLowerCase === 'd') { // Move to down
            if (this.x < this._fields.length - 1) { // Verify that is not down more that edge
                this._fields[this.x][this.y] = this._pathCharacter;
                this.x += 1;
            } else {
                this.gameOver = true;  // In case the player find a hole
                console.log("You cannot move more to down edge");
            }
        } else if (input.toLowerCase === 'l') { // Move to left
            if (this.y > 0) { // Verify that is not move more to left edge
                this._fields[this.x][this.y] = this._pathCharacter;
                this.y -= 1;
            } else {
                this.gameOver = true;  // In case the player find a hole
                console.log("You cannot move more to left edge");
            }
        } else if (input.toLowerCase === 'r') { // Move to right
            if (this.y < this._fields[this.y].length - 1) { // Verify that is not move more to right edge
                this._fields[this.x][this.y] = this._pathCharacter;
                this.y += 1;
            } else {
                this.gameOver = true;  // In case the player find a hole
                console.log("You cannot move more to right edge");
            }
        } else {
            this.gameOver = true; // In case the player find a hole
            console.log("Error... Errror... Error...\nYour input is only {u as up}, {d as down}, {l as left} & {r as right}.");
            return;
        }
        if (this._fields[this.x][this.y] === this._hat) {
            console.log("Yoo find your hat!!!\nWinner!!!\nWinner!!!\nWinner!!!");
            this.gameOver = true;  // If the player found your hat
        } else if (this._fields[this.x][this.y] === this._hole) {
            console.log("I am sorry but your lost!!!\nTry again!.");
            this.gameOver = true;  // In case the player find a hole
        }
    } ```


When you are unsure of what part of the code might be failing, it is best to include the entire script. When experiencing errors that have undefined in the error message, it means you have not initialised a variable before using it, so the example script needs to include all cases where the possible variables a declared. In this code example you have not shown where any of member level variables are declared which makes it hard to provide a good solution for you without a lot of guess work. Please update to show your member field/variable declarations.

You need to declare _fields and initialise it before you call print();
or in your print() function you should validate that it exists first.
The error message is telling you specifically that the object that you are calling foreach is not defined. In this case that means this._fields does not exist, so you cannot call operations on it.
One solution is to change your code to this:
print() {
        // I can prin the array, thanks design6726512087 he is in the forum of codecademy
        console.clear();
        if (this._fields) {
            this._fields.forEach(rows => {
                console.log(rows.join(''));
            });
        }
    }


It is not even clear if instructionsToMove() initialises the _fields array.

Given that playGame() is the logical entry point, another solution is to explicitly ensure that this._field is initialised before all other logic is executed. You must have some logic for this already, so modify playGame() to call that logic first:
playGame() {
        // setup _fields and any other variables you might need before executing the game loop.
        initializeGame();
        while (!this.gameOver) {      
            this.print();      
            const promptInputUser = prompt("Instructions to move is: {u as up}, {d as down}, {l as left} & {r as right}.\nWich is your path? ");
            // Call the function to move into array 
            this.instructionsToMove(promptInputUser);
        }
        console.log("Game Over");
    }

Then in the initializeGame() function you can instantiate all the variables your game needs
initializeGame() {
    // TODO: init this._hat, a character that represents a hat on the board
    // TODO: init this._hole, a character that represents a hole on the board
    // TODO: init this._pathCharacter, a character that shows previous cells that have been entered

    // TODO: init this._fields as multidimensional array 
    //       where the first dimension defines vertical axis
    //       and the second dimension defines the horizontal axis
    const maxRows = 10; // Vertical axis, 0 = top
    const maxColumns = 10; // horizontal axis, 0 = left
    const defaultCellValue = ' ';
    this._fields = new Array(maxRows).fill().map(_ => new Array(maxColumns).fill(defaultCellValue));

    // TODO: init this.x as integer, starting vertical ordinate
    // TODO: init this.y as integer, starting horizontal ordinate

    // Set the start location
    this._fields[this.x,this.y] = this._pathCharacter;

    // TODO: randomly choose location for hat and hole to be placed on the board, making sure not to put either in the start location!
    allocateHats(1); // number of hats to generate
    allocateHoles(5); // number of holes to generate
    
    // ensure the game starts in a playable mode
    this.gameOver = false;
}

I didn't provide implementation of allocateHats(numberOfHats) and allocateHoles(numberOfHoles), I would randomly choose locations, but I leave that implemenation to you ;)

X as vertical and Y as horizontal component ordinates is confusing to me, but that is what I could deduce from the sample code. I would recommend swapping these concepts so that Y is vertical and X is horizontal as this would align better with established standards for cartesian plane coordinates.


@Jovanny please add relevant code into the question, not the comment. It has bad format and is very hard to read. .forEach() is getting called on _fields, use debug tools to find out why _fields is undefined

Thaks I'm going to check why _fields  is undefine, and change my comment.

Thanks to response but now if is not problem you know why I cannot get error this is the instructionsToMove().

Thanks, Chris Schaller, for giving me feedback and the new suggest I'm going to modify to get a solution.
Thanks, Lã Ngọc Hải to correct me about my comment.
I'm new here and it's my first time, so if I have a new problem I'm going to ask here.
